# Hide tableview header that contains a search bar under navbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a search bar in the tableview header. I want to offset the position of the search bar that it looks hidden under the nav bar until the user pulls down on the tableview to reveal a search bar.  I have looked everywhere to find this but cannot.  Can someone please point me in the right direction and or show me how do create this effect in iOS 9 and objective-c.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

// search is hidden in TableView by default

For swift

```
self.TableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0,self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height), animated: false)
```

For Objective c

```
[[self staffTableView] setContentOffset:[CGPointMake(0, frameHeight)] animated:YES];
```

When you pullDown it will reveal you `searchbar`(added in the headerview)

Hope this will help you to solve your problem. it was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y:(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)!)

self.tableView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
```

This is for regular navigation bar. For search controller:
 Replace `navigationController` and `navigationBar` with karthik's y coordinate.